# BST method that returns a list of values in a specified range Python implementation

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I want to return a list of sorted order, provided I'm given a start/stop value for the method. For example, if start=2 and end=8, then i want to return a list within that range, implicitly, of the values in the BST in sorted order.

Since I want it to be in sorted order and not allowed to post sort the list after the method call, I think i should traverse the bst via in order traversal. when I test my implementation, first first doctest return [7,9,11] instead of [5,7,9,11] as intended.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, List, Optional, Tuple

class BinarySearchTree:
    """Binary Search Tree class.

    # === Representation Invariants ===
    #  - If self._root is None, then so are self._left and self._right.
    #    This represents an empty BST.
    #  - If self._root is not None, then self._left and self._right
    #    are BinarySearchTrees.
    #  - (BST Property) If self is not empty, then
    #    all items in self._left are <= self._root, and
    #    all items in self._right are >= self._root.
    """
    def __init__(self, root: Optional[Any]) -> None:
        """Initialize a new BST containing only the given root value.

        If <root> is None, initialize an empty tree.
        """
        if root is None:
            self._root = None
            self._left = None
            self._right = None
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._left = BinarySearchTree(None)
            self._right = BinarySearchTree(None)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        """Return True if this BST is empty.

        >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(None)
        >>> bst.is_empty()
        True
        >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(10)
        >>> bst.is_empty()
        False
        """
        return self._root is None

    def items_in_range(self, start: Any, end: Any) -> List:
        """Return the items in this BST between <start> and <end>, inclusive.

        Precondition: all items in this BST can be compared with <start> and
        <end>.
        The items should be returned in sorted order.

        As usual, use the BST property to minimize the number of recursive
        calls.

        >>> bst = BinarySearchTree(7)
        >>> left = BinarySearchTree(3)
        >>> left._left = BinarySearchTree(2)
        >>> left._right = BinarySearchTree(5)
        >>> right = BinarySearchTree(11)
        >>> right._left = BinarySearchTree(9)
        >>> right._right = BinarySearchTree(13)
        >>> bst._left = left
        >>> bst._right = right
        >>> bst.items_in_range(4, 11)
        [5, 7, 9, 11]
        >>> bst.items_in_range(10, 13)
        [11, 13]
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            return []
        else:
            #use helper here
            if end >= self._root >= start:
                return (self._left._helper_items_in_range_left(start)
                        + [self._root]
                        + self._right._helper_item_in_range_right(end))
            elif self._root > end:
                return self._left.items_in_range(start,end)
            elif self._root < start:
                return self._right.items_in_range(start,end)
            else:
                pass

    def _helper_items_in_range_left(self, start):
        if self.is_empty():
            return []
        elif self._root < start:
            return []
        else:
            return self._left._helper_items_in_range_left(start) +\
                   [self._root] + self._right._helper_items_in_range_left(start)

    def _helper_item_in_range_right(self, end):
        if self.is_empty():
            return []
        elif self._root > end:
            return []
        else:
            return self._left._helper_item_in_range_right(end) + [self._root] +\
                   self._right._helper_item_in_range_right(end)
```

Comment: Please edit your code so we can actually test it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Note that I tested it using a different tree structure.

```
import itertools
from collections import deque
class BSTIterator(object):

    def __init__(self, root):
        # Constructor takes in a tree root
        self.stack = deque()
        self._get_min(root)

    def _get_min(self, root):
        # We need to create our stack, i.e. dive down the left
        curr = root
        while curr != None:
            self.stack.append(curr)
            curr = curr.left        

    def __iter__(self): # Return self as the iterator
        return self
    def __next__(self): # Every time `next` is called return our data.
        try:
            curr = self.stack.pop()
            self._get_min(curr.right)
            return curr.data
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
```

**Tree type used:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data
```

**Tested with:**

```
root = Node(8)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(1)
root.insert(7)
root.insert(12)
root.insert(121)
root.insert(23)
root.insert(19)
root.insert(9)
b_iter = BSTIterator(root)
# root.print_tree()

# Since we now have an iterator we can for loop over it
# such as
# y = [x for x in b_iter]
# or we can slice it like
y = [x for x in itertools.islice(b_iter, 2, 5)]
print(y)
```

**Prints:**

```
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how I would define a method returning a list of nodes from a given range (inclusive, non-decreasing order).

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def nodes_in_range(self, start, end):
        def search_range(node):
            if node is not None:
                if start <= node.value:
                    yield from search_range(node.left)
                if start <= node.value <= end:
                    yield node.value
                if end >= node.value:
                    yield from search_range(node.right)
        return list(search_range(self.root))
```